# Selenium's WaitForPageToLoad Waits even after page loaded and timeouts- Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium.waitforpagetoload method to wait in an ajax enabled webpage. When I run the test code, selenium waits even after the page has loaded and throws a "timed out waiting for action to complete" Exception. And I may have used waitforpagetoload in places where there isn't even a page load event. I presumed it just skips the part if the page is loaded. My code  is like this

```
selenium.click("id=elmnt_id");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("50000");
```

I'm using selenium-java version 2.33.
google Chrome 27.0

I found out that selenium.click() itself implicitly waits for pages to load after the click event. The timeout occurred inside click method. But the page loads after the click event in less than 10 seconds. selenium.click waits for more than 30 seconds and says timed out waiting for action to complete. Any advice is much appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how **org.openqa.selenium.internal.seleniumemulation.WaitForPageToLoad**
   works, but the package name says "internal.seleniumemulation" .  I am not sure what that means but because I don't know what "emulation" means in this context, I would instead choose to use a different method of waiting for the page to load, such as a JavaScriptExecutor or using a FluentWait method in a loop until the element is ready.

Comment: OP obviously uses Selenium RC and not Selenium WebDriver.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.    My suggestion of hand-rolling his own "wait for page to load" method still stands though.  By writing his own, instead of relying on the specific waitForPageToLoad method, he may learn to understand better why it fails in some respects.